# Предложение "самое главное"

Tags: синтаксис

Тут слово **самое** является определением, а слово **главное** - подлежащим? И предложение является назывным? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Что за предложение такое?

Answer (score 1):

Без контекста, конечно, не разберешься. Но, как мне кажется, '*самое главное*' будет считаться одним членом предложения, потому что это сложная форма превосходной степени прилагательного *главное*. Сложные (аналитические) формы превосходной степени прилагательных представлены сочетаниями форм положительной степени со словами самый и *наиболее (наименее)*: самый молодой, наиболее (наименее) значительный. В предложении такие образования должны рассматриваться как единое целое (как один член предложения).

Answer (score 1):

Определить член предложения вне предложения невозможно. Если все предложение состоит из этих слов, тогда требуется контекст.
Согласна, что форма превосходной степени - единое целое.